# Find control in gridview return null

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview written in asp.net (c#), the problem is when try to read data from the textbox return null.

```
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  DataKeyNames="Week#/Day" 
            OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
             onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" 
              OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
              OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
            OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" AllowPaging="true"
         PageSize="4" >
            <Columns>
             <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" CommandName="Update" text="Update" />
             <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" CommandName="Edit"  text="Edit"/
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Week#/Day" InsertVisible="False"
      SortExpression="Week#/Day">
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#
      Eval("Week#/Day") %>'></asp:Label>
                  </EditItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Saturday" SortExpression="Saturday">
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"
          Text='<%# Bind("Saturday") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                  </EditItemTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server"
           Text='<%# Bind("Saturday") %>'></asp:Label>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sunday" SortExpression="Sunday">
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"
              Text='<%# Bind("Sunday") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                  </EditItemTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server"
               Text='<%# Bind("Sunday") %>'></asp:Label>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>

                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Monday" SortExpression="Monday">
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"
               Text='<%# Bind("Monday") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                  </EditItemTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server"
                 Text='<%# Bind("Monday") %>'></asp:Label>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>

                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tuesday" SortExpression="Tuesday">
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Bind("Tuesday") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                  </EditItemTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server"
              Text='<%# Bind("Tuesday") %>'></asp:Label>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>

                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Wednesday"
                SortExpression="Wednesday">
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"
         Text='<%# Bind("Wednesday") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                  </EditItemTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server"
         Text='<%# Bind("Wednesday") %>'></asp:Label>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>

           </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I am fill it using datatable on edit call this method

```
      protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender,GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

        BindData();
    }
```

and on update call update method

```
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    { 
            //Retrieve the table from the session object.
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["All_Topics"];

           GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            TextBox d1, d2, d3, d4, d5;
            d1 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox1");
            d2 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox2");
            d3 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox3");
            d4 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox4");
            d5 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox5");    

            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Saturday"] = d1.Text;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Sunday"] = d2.Text;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Monday"] = d3.Text;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Tuesday"] = d4.Text;
            dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Wednesday"] = d5.Text;

       }
```

the problem is when read data from the textbox it is always null. How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hey please Make sure that do not re-binding the GridView on the PostBack of the page. This may be the cause of problem.

Always bind your grid on page load in side the below code.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack ){
// Code to bind the Grid
// BindData();
}
```

when you are click on `Row Update Command` it is firstly go to the page load event and on page load if you are not binding your grid like the given manner your grid is rebind and you will get null from text box.

Hope it will helps you.